# recovery and efi system partitions on secondary hard

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, efi, partition-recovery

i have two drives the ssd which have windows 10 on it and another 1tb hdd one that gonna contain only data but because i installed windows on it previously it has two partition recovery and efi system

my question is whats the pro and cons of deleting them (forget about the 600mb it will save) its now empty hard but in a couple of weeks i will fill half of it and i won't be able to format it so i want to be 100% sure im doing the right thing

Comment: The answer to your question depends on the state of your current Windows 10 installation. If the efi and recovery partitions are part of an old installation and no longer used, then delete them. If they are part of your current windows installation, then you'll break your system. Is there an efi and recovery partition on your SSD?

Comment: @Appleoddity yeah there are efi and recovery partitions in both the ssd and hdd actually when i was installing the windows i wasn't connecting the hdd at all so the computer doesn't need these partitions on the hdd

Comment: Then you have answered your own question. Just wipe the hdd and start fresh. Remove all partitions and create a new, single partition.

Comment: i used diskpart as disk management didn't have the option to delete them, but i wanted to see the pros and cons of deleting them